# Selecting member IDs as individual variables in a predictive healthcare model

Tags: feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction

I'm working on a penalized regression model that will predict the number of days until a member's readmission to a hospital following the next discharge, based on past episode data.

Many of the 28,474 members in my dataset have multiple episodes:

```
> memb_counts <- table(data$Member_Number)
  memb_counts

    1      2     3     4      5     6     7     8     9     10     11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24    25    26    27    28 
    16688  5251  2517  1382   754   529   358   233   173   129    95    78    55    41    40    28    19    14    16    16     9     5     8     3     8     3     2     1 
    29    30    31    32    33    36    39    40    41    42    47    54    67 
    1     3     1     1     2     2     1     1     1     2     1     1     1
```

Given that a large number of these members will continue to have hospitalization episodes in the future, I think it makes sense to include separate indicator variables for at least some of the member IDs in the training dataset.

However, now I'm faced with a dataset containing over 28,000 dimensions!

**Is there a feasible method (not manual selection) for determining which Member IDs to retain as predictors?** Principal components analysis? Perhaps I could exclude all members with fewer than 5 or 10 episodes from consideration, but I'm still facing a formidable dimensionality reduction problem.

Comment: You want to use a multilevel /mixed effects / hierarchical model.  The standard reference for this is Gelman and Hill: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/

Comment: @MatthewDrury Would a mixed effects model be appropriate when making predictions? Random effects would certainly control for member -level correlation between observations with a suitable correlation or covariance matrix, but I wouldn't be able to make specific predictions by member ID with random effects.

Comment: Why not?  You'd be able to make predictions for any member id in the data set that incorporate the information about them in your training data, and you would have an estimate of the average effect across member id's that you could use for a new member.  It seems to cover both bases.  Possibly we mean something different when we say "random effects", I know economists use that term in a different context (which unfortunately I don't really understand).

Comment: My understanding is that random effects don't affect the coefficient estimates but they will change the standard errors. If we assumed that all the member IDs in my data had the same number of observations (equal weight), wouldn't a mixed effect and a fixed effect model produce the same coefficient estimates? Maybe not, I should recheck my assumptions.

Comment: @MatthewDrury Nope, I was wrong! A simple test shows you *do* get different coefficient results comparing a fixed effect & mixed effect model on the same variables. Ok, I'll have to rethink this.

Comment: Yah.  I think of random effects on a group of variables as acting like a shrinkage on those parameter estimates.  Your patient id's with a smaller number of observations will have their effects shrunk towards the overall mean more than those with many observations.